# How to transfer data from txt file onto a DataGridView using Visual Basic

Tags: c#, datagridview, system.io.file

I currently have a textbox like this:

John-15feb23-Tuesday-6:00pm-bad luck

John2-18feb23-Wednsday-3:00pm-Unknown

John3-16feb23-Friday-5:00pm-bad luck

It is seperated by the '-' so I know that is has to go on a different column.

I'm having trouble passing that data into my DataGridVew. I am trying to pass it to a DataTable, then onto Datarows and from there pass it to my dataGrid.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable ss = new DataTable();

        ss.Columns.Add("Alumno");
        ss.Columns.Add("Profesor");
        ss.Columns.Add("Día");
        ss.Columns.Add("Hora");
        ss.Columns.Add("Asunto");

        DataRow row = ss.NewRow();

        String linea;
        try
        {
            StreamReader tem = new StreamReader("C:\\cardiel.txt");
            linea = tem.ReadLine();
            while (linea != null)
            {

                row["Alumno"] += linea.Split('-')+ "\n";
                row["Profesor"] += linea.Split('-') + "\n";
                row["Día"] += linea.Split('-') + "\n";
                row["Hora"] += linea.Split('-') + "\n";
                row["Asunto"] += linea.Split('-') + "\n";
                ss.Rows.Add(row);
                linea = tem.ReadLine();
                foreach (DataRow Drow in ss.Rows)
                {
                    int num = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value = Drow["Alumno"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = Drow["Profesor"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = Drow["Día"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[3].Value = Drow["Hora"].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[4].Value = Drow["Asunto"].ToString();
                }
            }
            tem.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
        }
```

If someone could give out pointers or help me, I would really appreciate it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to just get the data from the file into the DataGridView per the original question, it looks like you're taking extra steps.  This will send it to the DataGridView:

```
//Buffer for IO reading
const Int32 BufferSize = 512;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Open the file and keep it open while there are lines with using
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            //Open the reader and keep it open while reading non null lines
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
            {
                String line;
                //While the StreamReader is reading a line and it is not null, how to handle the line
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //Split the string into an array
                    string[] splitarray = line.Split('-');

                    //Add the pieces of the array as a new row into the DataGridView
                    //This should be inside of a try/catch block or have some validation to make sure the array is a certain length (5 in this case)
                    dataGridView.Rows.Add(splitarray[0], splitarray[1], splitarray[2], splitarray[3], splitarray[4]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Console.WriteLine(ex.message)
    }
}
```

You don't need a DataRow, a DataTable, or to loop through all of the rows every time the StreamReader reads another line(!).

**NOTE**: This will fail if the indexes change order.  It will also fail if there are not enough indexes with an IndexOutOfRange Exception.  Also if there are any more dashes in the data, it may mess with your order.

**IO Note**: If this is not done on a separate thread, the UI will freeze as you are using the main thread to perform this operation.  You could use a [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) to perform the IO and then apply the results with a BindingSource, mentioned below.

If you are using the DataTable and DataRow somewhere else then you can keep them, but they are not necessary to populate a DataGridView.

Now, if this file is very large with lots of lines, it will be EXTREMELY slow (from experience, I know) drawing this.  I would recommend using a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.7.2) if you expect this to have a lot (or even a few with redraws frequently).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I can see the logic in it, but when i tried to apply it, it seems as if it gets stuck in an indefinite loop, and the program crashes, is there a step I may be missing? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Updated to better represent how the code is structured based on your example and include how to properly handle the IO functions.  I hope this helps :)